# Do task for each date in table VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have this VBA that creates an Array based on values in my table "Analysetable"

```
Sub BestilAnalyser()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim OrderArray() As Variant
Dim xArray() As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For i = 1 To Range("AnalyseTable").Rows.Count

    If Not IsEmpty(Range("AnalyseTable[Date]")(i)) And _
        WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AnalyseTable[Bund]")(i).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 12), "=1") > 0 Then

        ReDim Preserve OrderArray(n)

        OrderArray(n) = i

        ReDim Preserve xArray(0 To 12 - 1, n)

        For j = 0 To 12 - 1
            If Range("AnalyseTable[Bund]")(i).Offset(0, 1 + j).Value = 1 Then
                xArray(j, n) = "x"
            End If
        Next j

        n = n + 1

    End If

Next i

Call WriteToOrderForm(OrderArray, xArray)

Call WriteEmail

For i = 0 To n - 1
    For j = 1 To 12
        If xArray(j - 1, i) = "x" Then
            Range("AnalyseTable[Bund]")(OrderArray(i)).Offset(0, j) = 2
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So what I would like some help with is how to write the VBA so it is making it do the code for each date in the col "AnalyseTable[Date]". The same date would most likely show up multiply times and then run the VBA for all 1. Nov, all 3. Nov and so on.

I hope that is doable.

Comment: I'm confused, once You are using name `Analysetable`, in other case `AnalyseTable` and in another `AnalyseTabel`, are You aware of that?

Comment: Yeah I missed that, that is now corrected

Answer (score 0):

Maybe normal for loop

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("AnalyseTable[Date]")
    Debug.Print cel.Value
    ' do some your code
Next cel
```

Comment: I have tried that solution, that was also my goto solution, but i just managed to get the VBA to run 400 times with all the data.. Maybe I should have reduced the amount of data for the test runs..